# Type alias allows assignment of arbitrary pointer although int* is expected

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have encountered an interesting issue today involving assignment to a pointer from a function pointer of non-matching type.

EDIT: shorter example inspired by @Frank:

```
void printSquare(int x) { printf("%d\n", x * x); }

int* foo() {
  using res_t = int*;

  return res_t(printSquare);
}
```

I would expect that the code does not compile, because the return-type of the function should be `int*`, which can by no means be created from a function-reference or -pointer within the boundaries of the type-system (as far as I am aware of). When directly returning or substituting `res_t` with `int *` the compiler rejects this program, but with the `using`-declaration in between, it compiles and runs (although of course the location pointed to does not contain an int, but a function).

Original code and question preserved below in separate answer.

Comment: So like... 99% of the code in your question is completely irrelevant to the question. Can you try to reduce it and provide a [mcve], emphasis on Minimal?

Comment: This is already distilled out of 3 original sources with 100+ lines each. Trust me if I find something trivial to remove where I am reasonably sure that it does not change the behaviour I will. Also 99% is a complete exaggeration. It's less than 100 lines, and ~ 20 lines are the 2 funcions and 20 the setup code.

Comment: Fundamentally, you're asking why a _single expression_ compiles when you expected it not to. Try just reducing the question to just a couple lines of code exposing that single expression. You should be able to do it within a few lines of codes, no includes, and no extra types.

Comment: Conversions between data pointer types and function pointer types are conditionally-supported in C++. What they do (if supported) is defined by your specific implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not constructing a pointer, but *casting* the pointer, which is legal under C-style pointer casting rules.

Case in point, the following is equivalent to what you are doing, and compiles just fine (unfortunately, but necessary for compatibility reasons):

```
float some_val = 0.0f;
int* foo() {
  using res_t = int*;

  return res_t(&some_val);
}
```

Off the top of my head, you could work around this like so:

```
if(pos != end(container)) {
  return pos->second;
}
else {
  C val(std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return val;
}
```

But I would be surprised if there isn't a more elegant way to do this.

**Edit:**

> Directly assigning or returning the mismatching pointer does not compile

Correct, but that's not what your are doing, you are not **assigning** the pointer, you are **casting** it. Syntactical casts are *extremely* loose. You've probably seen the following:

```
int * a;
float * b = (float*)a;
```

Now consider how casting works between numerical types:

```
int a = 0;
short b = (int)a;
short c = int(a);
```

The 'b' and 'c' statements are equivalent. The third statement is not a **construction**, it's still a **cast**, and the same gramatical rules apply to pointers (for consistency).

However: The syntax used by `c` (functional-style cast) is not directly accessible since the following makes no gramatical sense:

```
float* d = float*(&a);
```

But it can still work when using a type alias:

```
using float_ptr = float*;
float* d = float_ptr(&a);
```

Comment: I see that it works, however I don't understand why, yet. Directly assigning or returning the mismatching pointer does not compile, so why does the `using`-declaration enable this counter-intuitive behaviour?

Comment: @midor It does not compile because language grammar does not allow using `int *` directly in a functional-style cast. This is just a grammatical limitation. Replace functional-style cast with a c-style cast and it will compile even with `int *`.

Comment: @midor I've ammended my answer with further explanations.

Comment: A good and detailed explanation, yet I am very unhappy that this is the answer ;). In the reduced case I had a gut feeling why this works, but in the involved original piece of code where I found it with templates and perfect forwarding involved, I did not think about this possibility at all. I am considering updating the title to make this easier to find. Suggestions are very welcome.